# Why Mockito "when" method generate NullpointerException?

Tags: junit, mockito

Hello Guys I am trying to test my controller but i am getting **nullpointException** at  Mockito "when" method in the class TodoControllerTest.getAllToDos()  ( please see the pic [image]), I dont know why?

```
 @ExtendWith(value ={SpringExtension.class})
    @WebMvcTest
    public class TodoControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        MockMvc mockMvc;


        @MockBean
        private ToDoService toDoService;

        @Test
        public void getAllToDos() throws Exception {
            List<ToDo> toDoList = new ArrayList<ToDo>();
            toDoList.add(new ToDo(1L,"Eat Eggs",true));
            toDoList.add(new ToDo(2L,"Sleep Twice",true));
            when(toDoService.findAll()).thenReturn(toDoList);

            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/todos")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    ).andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2))).andDo(print());
        }

    }


    @Service
    public class ToDoService {
        public List<ToDo> findAll() {
            return new ArrayList<ToDo>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you run the unit test?

Comment: first of all i am using Eclipse Exygen + My App (java 8 + JUnit 5) Cause of Bug - using Junit5 while the runner Test is Junit 4 in the eclipse Oxygen (this version of eclipse support only JUnit3 & Junit 4 Runner Test). solution : I change the eclipse to the last version that supported Junit 5 Runner Test, and now works fine

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) instead @ExtendWith(value ={SpringExtension.class})
because the prject with JUnit4

Comment: how come you are using Junit4? while you are having SpringExtension class on your classpath. SpringExtension uses Junit5 by default. can you paste your build file in the question.

Comment: first of all i am using Eclipse Exygen + My App (java 8 + JUnit 5)

Cause of Bug - using Junit5 while the runner Test is Junit 4 in the eclipse Oxygen (this version of eclipse support only JUnit3 & Junit 4 Runner Test).
solution : I change the eclipse to the last version that supported Junit 5 Runner Test, and now works fine with @ExtendWith(value ={SpringExtension.class})

do you get my point @SasiKathimanda?